# mixin for handling grid layout

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I created a sass `@mixin` for handling Grid Layout.

But there are several problems I ran into :

1. If only rows are needed I want to remove `grid-template-columns` property and vice-versa.
2. Also If only `row-gap` is needed `column-gap` and `gap` should not get involved and same for `column-gap` and `gap` (or you can say vice-versa)
3. If **spacing** is not needed I don't want to add `gap` or `row-gap` or `column-gap`

Below is my attempt but it is not working like I wanted on the first place.

```scss
@mixin grid($rows, $columns: "", $row-gap: 0, $column-gap: 0, $gap: 0) {
  @if ($columns) {
    display: grid;

    @if ($gap) {
      gap: $gap;
    } @else {
      row-gap: $row-gap;
      column-gap: $column-gap;
    }

    grid-template-rows: $rows;
    grid-template-columns: unquote($columns);
  } @else {
    display: grid;

    @if ($gap) {
      gap: $gap;
    } @else {
      row-gap: $row-gap;
      column-gap: $column-gap;
    }

    grid-template-rows: $rows;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem (in case anybody will ran into the same problem) I am posting it here.

You don't need to do anything just default set `null` value of all `params`.

```scss
@mixin grid($rows: null, $columns: null, $gap: null, $row-gap: null, $column-gap: null) {
  display: grid;
  gap: $gap;
  row-gap: $row-gap;
  column-gap: $column-gap;
  grid-template-rows: $rows;
  grid-template-columns: $columns;
}
```

and use it like this

**If you only want `rows`**

```scss
@include grid(repeat(2, 1fr));
```

**If you want `rows` and `columns`**

```scss
@include grid(repeat(2, 1fr), repeat(3, 1fr));
```

**If you want `columns` but not `row`** same goes with `gap`, `row-gap` or `column-gap`

```scss
@include grid($columns: repeat(3, 1fr));
```